# Proof by induction for all positive $n$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have to prove by induction that the following inequality holds for all positive $n$. I am unsure on how to approach this problem so any hint would be immensely appreciated

\begin{align}\binom{2n}{n} > \frac {2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \end{align}

Comment: Can you solve the base case?

Comment: @CyclotomicField well for the base case i would set n = 1, and this is trivially true. For the inductive step, I would be looking at n = n + 1 step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1$, the inequality is
$$2= {2 \choose 1} > \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

which is true since $\sqrt{\pi} > 1$.

Now let's suppose that $${2n \choose n} > \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

holds for a certain integer $n$, and let's prove the same inequality for $n+1$. One has
$${2(n+1) \choose n+1} = \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!^2} = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}{2n \choose n} > \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\times\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

using the induction hypothesis. You deduce that $${2(n+1) \choose n+1}  > \frac{2n+1}{n+1}\times\frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \quad \quad (*)$$

Now you trivially have
$$\frac{2n+1}{n+1} > 1 > \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

so introducing this in $(*)$, you deduce
$${2(n+1) \choose n+1}  > \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\times\frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi n}} = \frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi(n+1)}}$$

and you are done.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. Apart from being against [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513), it is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their [assessed homework or exam](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33557/10513), so giving them the complete answer is unfair to the rest of their class.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer** (please don't downvote, it is the only way I can insert a graphics) but a remark: this inequality

$$\underbrace{\binom{2n}{n}}_{\text{red circles}} > \underbrace{\frac{2^n}{ \sqrt{\pi n}}}_{\text{green stars}}$$

is very far from being **tight** compared to this one :

$$\underbrace{\binom{2n}{n}}_{\text{red circles}} > \underbrace{\frac{4^n}{2 \sqrt{n}}}_{\text{blue asteriscs}}$$

For more, see this excellent [document](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/approx/SimpleCases.html).

Here are plotted on a logscale (!) the 3 expressions for $n=1,2,... 20$:

[image]